# Downloading app onto iPad for testing

Tags: ios, ipad

I'm trying to test an app by downloading it onto an iPad. I'm following the directions at https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html, and I'm trying to use Xcode to install the app. However, the Installed Apps table that is mentioned in that section doesn't appear after choosing the device. Would anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Do you have a valid Apple Developer Account?

Comment: Yeah, I paid the 99$ and everything.